# How to generate frequency response given b,a coefficients of the system?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, digital-filter

I have the following system, specified by the set of coefficients:

```
b = [1 2 3];
a = [1 .5 .25];
```

In the Z-Domain, such function will have the following transfer function:

```
 H(Z) = Y(Z)/X(Z)
```

So the frequency response will be just the unit circle, where:

```
 H(e^jw) = Y(e^jw)/X(e^jw)
```

Do I just substitute in the `e^jw` for 'Z' in my transfer function to obtain the frequency response of the system mathematically, on paper? Seems a bit ridiculous from my (a student's) point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `freqz()`? It returns the frequency response vector, `h`, and the corresponding angular frequency vector, `w`, for the digital filter with numerator and denominator polynomial coefficients stored in `b` and `a`, respectively.

In your case, simply follow the help:

```
[h,w]=freqz(b,a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do sub in e^jw for Z. This isn't ridiculous. Then you just sweep w from -pi to pi. Your freq response will be the absolute value of the result.

As Alessiox mentioned, freqz is the command you want to use in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

I would indeed be as simple as substituting `exp(j*w)` in your transfer function. There are of course different ways to implement this with Matlab. For the purpose of illustration, I will be assuming `b`s are the coefficients of the `x` sequence and `a`s are the coefficients of the `y` sequence, such that the `b` are in the numerator and the `a`s are in the denominator:

[image]

A direct evaluation with Matlab could be done with:

```
b = [1 2 3];
a = [1 .5 .25];

N = 513; % number of points at which to evaluate the transfer function
w = linspace(0,2*pi,N);
num = 0;
for i=1:length(b)
  num = num + b(i) * exp(-j*i*w);
end
den = 0;
for i=1:length(a)
  den = den + a(i) * exp(-j*i*w);
end
H = num ./ den;
```

This would be equivalent to the following which makes use of the builtin [`polyval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html):

```
N = 513; % number of points at which to evaluate the transfer function
w = linspace(0,2*pi,N);
H = polyval(fliplr(b),exp(-j*w))./polyval(fliplr(a),exp(-j*w));
```

Also, this is really evaluating the transfer function at discrete equally spaced angular frequencies `w = 2*pi*k/N` which corresponds to the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT). As such it could also be done with:

```
N = 512;
H = fft(b,N) ./ fft(a,N);
```

Incidentally this is what [`freqz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) does, so you could also get the same result with:

```
N = 512;
H = freqz(b,a,N,'whole');
```